# Flutter Navigation's then callback isn't working if I use pushAndRemoveUntil in the upcoming screens

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-navigation

I am stuck with this issue for a while now and didn't find any answers. I have a scenario something similar to below.

I have 3 screens, user progresses through them in the below way:

**Home -> Listing Screen -> Add Screen**

My Add screen is used at multiple places and above is one way.

When I add data in the **Add Screen** I am using below method to navigate back to previous screen. (Assume I have passed right condition and screen here because it goes back to Listing Screen)

```
static pushAndRemoveUntil(
      BuildContext context, Widget screen, Function condition) {
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => screen,
      ),
      (route) {
        return condition(route) || route is HomeScreen || route.isFirst;
      },
    );
  }
```

I go back to the **Listing Screen** and then press back button and I go back to **Home Screen** as expected .

**Now the problem is in the Home Screen I'm listening to the result like below**

```
  void onAddData(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const Listing()),
    ).then(
      (value) => refreshData(),
    );
  }
```

But my **refreshData** is not called in this scenario.

(Other scenarios works. Is it something to do with `pushAndRemoveUntil` ? )